# Execute protractor command in console to debug protractor

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor, automated-tests, google-chrome-devtools

How can I execute **protractor commands** in chrome developer tool console tab, without being disconnected from protractor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually chrome devtools don’t allow this. You can’t open devtool window in chrome while your tests are running, you can pause your test and and then inspect something in devtools.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/help/devtools-window-keeps-closing

Also you can use elementExplorer option of protractor and run commands in terminal to better debug protractor. Run

```
protractor —elementExplorer
```

in terminal. This will open new chrome window. Open any page and run protractor commands in terminal.

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/debugging.md

Comment: @RahulSingh Install protractor globally via `npm install -g protractor`